# Why did the Vampires of Venice flee to Earth?

Tags: doctor-who, the-silence

In the S5 episode of the modern [*Doctor Who*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who), [*The Vampires of Venice*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Vampires_of_Venice), the Vampires reveal they fled their home due to The Silence.  Prior to fleeing through the crack to Earth, they used it to glimpse many worlds.  On many planets, they "saw Silence", so they have some method of detecting the Silence.  In the [S6](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_Who_%28series_6%29) premiere, we're introduced to [the Silence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silence_%28Doctor_Who%29), and learn they have been

> running Earth secretly for millenia.

So, given that spoiler, why would the Vampires flee to Earth?  It seems like Earth is the *last* place they would want to go.

Comment: What if The Silence's plans on earth were not known to the Vampire and hidden. It could be that they were hidden from the whole galaxy...

Comment: That they knew what they were fleeing implies they knew of some way to detect The Silence though.

Comment: It could be the silence found a way around that technology. I wouldn't know the exact reasoning. I'll watch the premier (somehow) and let you know my thoughts.

Comment: It may be that the answer to this question will be revealed later in the Season 6.

Comment: This question talks about the silence and maybe they should be linked... I have a feeling I know what they are... but not really. http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3358/who-is-the-eye-patch-woman/3369#3369

Comment: From a real-world perspective, Steven Moffat didn't write/direct/produce that episode so he probably didn't check the script, and he may not have told the writer enough about the Silence for the full implications to become apparent (or the writer may have misunderstood).

Comment: I rewatched the episode recently, and they explicitly did not go to some other worlds due to seeing the Silence on them, so this is technically still a mystery.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect that the nature of The Silence changed in S6 when what we're introduced to was dreamed up. The end of S5 was a pretty convincing interpretation, don't you think -- had those events been allowed to unfold, that would be pretty silent.

> The Vampires of Venice were fleeing the destruction of their home world as a result of the TARDIS's destruction taking the universe with it (and taking its sweet time in doing so). It is certainly conceivable that the phrase "The Silence" could apply to multiple things/events; heck, right here on real-life Earth we've had no shortage of cultures that each call themselves simply "The People", despite having no connection whatsoever to each other. Thus, the Vampires could call the destruction of their home world "The Silence", while the creatures we meet in the premier of S6 could likewise call themselves The Silence. Further, if you keep thinking about it, *no one knows about The Silence* that we meet in S6. It could very well be that their name for their race has been subconsciously embedded in the minds of everything, so when a big calamity befalls the universe people immediately all latch onto "The Silence" as the name for it.

This is all just conjecture on my part. In truth, I think it is actually a non sequitur, and that The Silence as we're shown in S5 is exactly what it was meant to be, while The Silence we meet in S6 is a later addition never intended by the events/actions/words of S5.

Or, as @Jeff suggests, maybe the Vampires really did think they were escaping The Silence, unaware of their presence on Earth. Seems a pretty logical explanation given the nature of the latter.

After thinking about and writing this answer, I now have a powerful urge to go back and re-watch the entirety of S5... And, heck, while I'm at it, 1-4 as well!

Comment: but the escaped prisoner in the S5 opener also said that 'Silence will fall'.  Also at the end of the S5 finale, *The Big Bang*, The Doctor said 'the Silence is still out there'.  I thought it was clear from the hints during S5 that the Silence was a species or group of people who were threatening the universe.  There are also indications that a few times in S5 people saw Silence off-screen.

Comment: @Keen Did he? Hm, I don't recall that part, I'll have to watch it again. If that's true (not that I have any reason to doubt you), then much of my answer really isn't plausible after all. @Jeff's still stands, though -- the Vampires quite likely didn't know The Silence were on Earth.

Answer (score 3):

My guess would be the Vampires didn't know what you put in the spoiler when they chose this planet.

Comment: Um... not helping the question.

Comment: To the contrary @Justin, I think that explains it perfectly.

Comment: How? Just out of curiosity.

Comment: @Justin If the Vampires didn't know what's in the spoiler, then there would be no reason NOT to choose Earth.  Ergo, them not knowing is an appropriate answer to the question.

Comment: The Vampires should have read the spoiler first, methinks...

Comment: True... I guess... still I don't like the one sentence answer. Just preference, mostly my old school teachers fault. I can here them now. Lol...